# Put my video in an HTML tag

Tags: html, video

I'm recording video from my raspberry with motionEye (for a security system) but if I try to insert them in an HTML page they don't work.
How can I do?

These are motionEye codecs:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pDFr.png

And this is my tag video:

```
<video style="width: 23%; height: 23%; margin-right: 5%; margin-left: 5%; margin-bottom: 5%;" controls><source src="/home/pi/Desktop/video/2018-05-26/14-27-06.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

**UPDATE**

The web page show me these video but I can't play them. With chrome they are gray and with firefox there is a MIME compatibility problem.

Web page and videos are on my Raspberry (with Raspbian), in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from the **src**, try to put the full path of the video.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this video in a Windows computer, then your `src` should be something like this:

```
src="file:///C:/Users/{USERNAME}/Documents/home/pi/Desktop/video/2018-05-26/14-27-06.mp4"
```

If you have the video uploaded to a server:

```
src="http://{NAMEOFDOMAIN.COM}/{PATH}/{TO}/home/pi/Desktop/video/2018-05-26/14-27-06.mp4"
```

BTW, if you are encoding video use the most compatible codec: `H264` When choosing codecs, file types, means of delivery, etc., always aim for the widest range of users.

---

### Demo

---

```html
<video style="width: 23%; height: 23%; margin-right: 5%; margin-left: 5%; margin-bottom: 5%;" controls><source src="file:///C:/Users/{USERNAME}/Documents/home/pi/Desktop/video/2018-05-26/14-27-06.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Comment: these video are on Raspbian and the web page is in the same folder of videos

Comment: If you want to play OMX on desktop use a player like OMXPlayer or have a couple of encoded versions of each video you intend to upload and host. It would of course make more sense that you do the latter because the average person doesn't have a blackberry and don't expect people to install special software just to see your videos. unless that's the only type of user your site supports...o_o